# Constructing homomorphisms between a group and its subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

How would I go about constructing a homomorphism between a group and its subgroup. For example, the group multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$ and the subgroup of the squares of its elements $\{1,4\}$.

Also, in general how would I construct a homomorphism between two groups without generators.

(I'm just at A-level, so I would like a simple explanation)

Comment: Are you familiar with quotient maps/cosets?

Comment: I don't think the subgroup of squares of the elements of Z/15Z is {1,4}, did you mean Z/5Z? To get a homomorphism from an abelian group to the subgroup of squares, the map x-> x^2 would work. Also, going the other way, the identity gives a homomorphism from a subgroup to a group. I don't know what you mean by 'between two groups without generators'

Comment: In general, I don't think there's a natural homomorphism between a group and a subgroup. A quotient group, yes, but that's not necessarily a subgroup. The image of a homomorphism G->G is a subgroup but not all subgroups can be expressed this way.

Comment: For the groups with no generators I meant non cyclic groups. And what do u mean by the identity giving a homomorphism from a subgroup to a group?

Comment: I guess the more proper term is 'inclusion', not identity. If H is a subgroup of G, there is a map H->G that just takes h->h. It's a homomorphism.

Comment: If it just maps h to h that isnt surjective could the there be a surjective one? And by the sqaure of elements I meant if you squared all the elements of z/15Z you get a subgroup {1,4} then how would you get a surjective homomorphism between the subgroup {1,4}  and the muliplicative group of Z/15Z =  {1,2,4,6,7,8,11,13}

Comment: No. It's injective, so if it were surjective it would be a isomorphism. Regarding {1,4}, oh, I see, sorry, I got confused with the additive group (which I shouldn't have cause squares it wouldn't be a subgroup otherwise). I assume you want a surjective homomorphism from {1,2,4,6,7,8,11,13} to {1,4} (the other way would be impossible). For that, my original suggestion of using the map g->g^2 holds up.

Comment: As a general rule a group should be given as a set *with a multiplication*. There is no "group $\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$". However, there is an additive group on this set. There is also a related multiplicative group, but it is on a subset of this set. Also, the notation $\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$ sort of implies it is an additive group, because it sort of implies you are viewing it as a quotient group of the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$...

Answer (score 5):

If your group $G$ is a finite abelian group then every subgroup of $G$ is a homomorphic image of $G$. This follows from the classification of these groups (the fundamental theorem for finite abelian groups). The multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian so there exists a homomophism to the subgroup consisting of the squares of elements: it is simply the map $x\mapsto x^2$, as was pointed out in the comments.

However, in general if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ there does not exist a surjective homomorphism $G\twoheadrightarrow H$. For example, consider the alternating group $G=A_5$. This is a subgroup of the permutation group $S_5$ (if you are going through a text book, these groups will almost certainly be covered!). Now $A_5$ is simple. This means that every normal subgroup is either trivial or the whole group; in terms of homomorphic images, this means that every homomorphism $\phi: A_5\rightarrow H$ has trivial image or its image is isomorphic to $A_5$ (by the first isomorphism theorem). In particular, if we have $\phi:A_5\rightarrow H$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $A_5$ then the image of $\phi$ is trivial. (Note that the group $A_5$ contains proper, non-trivial subgroups; abelian simple groups, such as the cyclic group of order $3$, do not contain any proper, non-trivial subgroups.)